# Переместить placeholder вверх input'а

Tags: html, css

Каким образом можно вынести текст в `placeholder` в левый верхний угол окна ввода?

[Пример кода](http://jsfiddle.net/xb7801Lq)

```css
.test {
  height: 50px
}

.test::placeholder {}
```

```html
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <input placeholder="Текст комментария" class="test" type="text" name="name" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
input {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="что то">
```

Comment: Не стоит забывать, что это не будет работать в `EDGE && IE`

Comment: @programmer403, зато есть `:-ms-input-placeholder` :)

Comment: @programmer403, вот список с указанием браузеров: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30827689/4928642

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87491/discussion-on-answer-by----placeholder--input).